# Index out of Range fault

Tags: python

I am pretty new with python and I cannot shake this "index out of range error" at line `wks.insert_row([row[1],row[2],row[3]], 1)`. I am trying to send the data to google sheets but it is not working. The `wks.insert_row([1,2,3],1)` does send 1,2, and 3 to the sheet. It must be something with row[1], row[2], row[3]. I have tried removing `wks.insert_row([1,2,3],1)` and changing the index to random numbers, still does not work. Thank you for the help!

```
import csv
import gspread
import time

MONTH = 'July'

file = f"Chase_{MONTH}.csv"

transactions = []

def ChaseFin(file):

    with open(file, mode = 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            date = row[1]
            name = row[2]
            amount = row[3]
            transaction = ((date, name, amount))
            print(transaction)
            transactions.append(transaction)
        return transactions
  

sa = gspread.service_account()
sh = sa.open("Personal Finances")

wks = sh.worksheet(f"{MONTH}")

rows = ChaseFin(file)

for row in rows:
    wks.insert_row([row[1],row[2],row[3]], 1)
    time.sleep(2)

wks.insert_row([1,2,3],1)
```

Comment: Python is zero-indexed. So `row[1]` means the second element of row. If transaction has three elements, `row[3]` is the fourth element, and is out of range.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Iterating over a string in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/17793743/90527)", "[Does "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to access the N'th item mean that my list has less than N items?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1098643/90527)"